# Simple boost::thread usage crash

Tags: boost-thread

This code crash, sometimes :

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
struct ThreadData 
{
   int t,f; // dummy, but without this it's not crashing
   int number;
};

// this is what each thread does...
void MyThreadFunction(ThreadData* threadData) 
{ 
   for (int i=0;i<100000000;++i)
   {
      threadData->number++; // without this it's not crashing
   }
}

int main()
{       
   const int MaxThreads(5);
   ThreadData threadData[MaxThreads];// if it's global app is not crashing
   boost::thread hThreadArray[MaxThreads]; 
   for( int i=0; i<MaxThreads; i++ )
   {
      hThreadArray[i] = boost::thread(MyThreadFunction,threadData+i);
   } 

   boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
   for(int i=0; i<MaxThreads; i++)
   {
      hThreadArray[i].detach();
   }
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000)); // wait for threads to die
}
```

I'm using win32, MSVC2012, boost1.52.
When I put threadData global, or remove the dummy ints in ThreadData it's ok.
It fails on the main thread, with access violation executing some address. 
When it crashes, there are 2 threads still alive.
Any ideas?

Comment: You need to join every thread before exiting from main function. sleep is not a good solution. Also, provide more information, where exactly the program crashes.

Comment: Possibly the program crashes, when main function exits, ThreadData array is destroyed, but some worker threads are still alive. Again, join is the solution.

Comment: But I don't want the thread to finish. I want to kill it - and that's the meaning of detach, isn't it? From the doc. : "In this case, the boost::thread object ceases to represent the now-detached thread, and instead represents Not-a-Thread."

Comment: detach doesn't kill the thread - it just removes the relation between thread object and running thread (kind of "run and forget"). Killing thread creates huge memory and resource leak. Standard solution is join - before the program exits, ensure that all running threads stopped.

Comment: Tnx alex. But how do I stop the thread from doing it's work and terminate the process?